# App signing key certificate is the same as the Upload key certificate

Tags: android, google-play-console

Can someone explain to me why the app signing key certificate is the same as the upload key certificate? I have selected the option to google manage my app signing key and in my understanding they should be different.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTED1.png)

Answer (score 0):

This mean that you have a regular key that you signed your app with before giving Google the permission to mange your app signing.

This is not a bad thing and you can leave it like that. But if you want it to be different with stronger key you should `Request key upgrade`, but you need to login from the owner account.

[image: screen]